# Nginx reverse-proxy redirects any subdomain while I only configured one redirection

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to use Nginx to redirect to specific applications based on the subdomain of the request.

For now I only have one application which has its own server listening on port 3080. I would like the subdomain `gitea.mydomain.com` to redirect to the application server which is listening on `localhost:3080`.

I created a file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` with this content:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gitea.mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3080;
    }
}
```

Well it works too well and I can try anything as a subdomain, or no subdomain at all, and I'm redirected to the app.

For the DNS, I have two A records, one for redirecting my domain to my IP address, and the other one to redirect *.mydomain.com to my IP address.

Isn't that how I am supposed to do that subdomain-redirection?

Thanks for your help guys

**EDIT**
Pothi Kalimuthu's answer solved my problem but I have a follow-up question. Why does Nginx redirected to the application when I told it to redirect only the subdomain? I expected other requests to fail.

Comment: nginx's virtual host selection algorithm is designed this way, that is why it works like this. You can ready more about the algorithm at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to add a catch-all server block to take care of every other subdomain and other domains such as `example.net` or `example.org` ...

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name _;

   return 444;
}
```

Note #1: Please be sure to reload or restart Nginx to apply changes.

Note #2: Please note that the above block basically returns nothing. The error code 444 is an Nginx specific error code that means "no response". Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#nginx

Comment: @jeahel ... you may use any status code, such as 403, in place of the existing 444. I hope that helps.

Comment: Even custom error codes are allowed. That can be used to display a custom error message such as "this domain is not hosted here". For an example, please see https://github.com/pothi/wordpress-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/default.conf (shameless plug: that's my config).

Comment: It works, thank you! But I have a follow-up question now. I edited the original post to add it.